# Generating a vertical proportion curve gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am looking to generate a vertical proportion curve using GNUPlot. Here is a sample of what the data file looks like

```
53.2504 .2756 .0570 .0000 .0000 .6673
53.7504 .2909 .0703 .0000 .0000 .6388
54.2504 .3139 .0831 .0000 .0000 .6030
54.7504 .3441 .0941 .0000 .0000 .5618
55.2504 .3786 .1028 .0000 .0000 .5187
```

The first column represent the Y coordinate and the last 5 columns represent the fraction of the X-axis at the y location that should be represented by a different color for each color. The first row of data would look similar to the image linked below

[image: First Row of data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will use plot style "with vectors" which requires x, y, delta_x, delta_y in the using specifier.   In your case y is in column 1, delta_y is always zero, delta_x is in column N.  The only tricky part is to calculate the start point x for each line segment N.  For that we define a function start(N).  "as 1" is shorthand for "arrowstyle 1".

```
set xrange [0:1]
set style arrow 1 nohead linewidth 5
unset key

start(N) = (N == 2) ? 0.0 : sum [i=2:N-1] column(i)

plot for [N=2:6] 'frac.dat' using (start(N)):1:N:(0) with vector as 1
```

Comment: This works perfectly, Thanks you so much